# Alphanumeric Regular Expression String

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for an alphanumeric string.

The following are all valid characters:

```
+0123456789BC
```

Valid strings are:

```
+445677BBCC
12345
44556677 etc
```

Basically rules are:

- May or may not start with +
- Followed by one or more digits 0-9
- Followed by zero or more B's or C's in any order

Currently have:

```
^\+?[0-9]+[BC]+?$
```

But this is not exactly what I need.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will have to escape the `+`, and the metacharacter after `[BC]` needs to be `*` for "zero or more" instead of `+` for one or more. You also don't need the `?` at the end since there's no need to make this a non-greedy match; you're matching till the end of the string anyway:

```
/^\+?\d+[BC]*$/
```

Otherwise, what you have is not really a valid regex. There is nothing to repeat for the `+` at the beginning, and the `^` is just an anchor for the beginning of the string.

Comment: Well, Java for one [seems ok with an unescaped +](http://ideone.com/3artTt), well, unless you [remove the start and end of string anchors](http://ideone.com/Aj4ybN).

Comment: @Dukeling fair point; although in my defense OP didn't mention the dialect of the regex he was using :). I really hate the way Java does regexes. :p